# Wsfederation Error. Registration form keeps popping for a registered user after token has expired

Tags: asp.net-core, ws-federation

I have implemented the WSFederation successfully on Asp.net core as per this doc [WSf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2). When the idle time of 20 mins lapses, the application re-authenticates by calling the ADFS page. However, the application takes the registered user back to the registration page. I will then either recycle the application pool or restart the website to make it work again. How do I resolve the issue ?[image: My registration form]. The console is showing error 401

Answer (score 0):

```
on start up
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddWsFederation(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "Login Using Office Account",
options =>
{
   options.MetadataAddress = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/FederationMetadata/2007-
  06/FederationMetadata.xml";

    options.Wtrealm = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.org/";
}).AddCookie();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
            }
        );
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Index");
and on logout

//delete all cookies first
foreach (var key in HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys)
 {
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
 }

    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
     return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home/Index" }, 
     CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
     WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    enter code here

The solution I found that works were to increase the application pool idle time from default 20 minutes to any minutes of choice. The user can then work and logout of the application without issues. You can also review the code I have and suggest some improvements if needed
```